# How to disable automatic generate file flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, translation, intl

I have an older Flutter project where at that time I implemented translations with `intl` package.

Now as I migrated project to new Flutter version and also to last `intl_utils` package version, the generated files from `intl` are in `.dart_tool` directory.

But the issue is that the `lib/generated` directory is still created automatically even if I am deleting it.

I noticed that a command is run automatically before the directory is created: `flutter pub global run intl_utils:generate`.

How can I disable this behaviour?

Comment: If there is a line `generate: true` under `flutter:` in your pubspec.yaml, remove it.

Comment: Thanks! I also had `flutter_intl: enable: true` and I removed it too.